# "Responsible" as predicate adjective

Tags: grammar

*"They are the only responsible for the situation"*

*"They are the only ones responsible for the situation"*

*"They are the only one responsible for the situation"*

Which of these options is/are grammatically correct? There are many hits for all of them in Google.

I would've thought the third option is incorrect.

Comment: The first is not strictly ungrammatical. 'The Meerkat Group started the fight. Of the different groups present, they are the only one responsible ...'. Synesis, but very clumsy; I'd rephrase. /  'They are the only responsible for the situation' is incorrect, like 'He is the only talking'.

Comment: Only your second example is correct. Anaphoric plural "they" requires plural "ones" since they both refer to the same plural antecedent.

Comment: @BillJ Of all the teams playing, they are the only one to have won all their matches. I'd say that this is not unacceptable (though clumsy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "They are the only responsible for the situation"

This sentence is ungrammatical because *the* is a definite article which can only modify nouns, and there is only an adjective present. You could, however, restructure it to be *Only they are responsible for the situation*.

> "They are the only ones responsible for the situation"

Here *they* refers to a group of people, and *ones* agrees with this plurality.

> "They are the only one responsible for the situation"

Though there has been some debate about it in the past, many people accept *they* as a gender-neutral third person singular pronoun, otherwise referred to as the [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). Accordingly, *one* agrees with this.